# Get fields as array comma separated

Tags: php

Given a string

```
$str= "name1 surname2, name2 midname2 surname2";
```

There are two persons, one has two values (name, surname) while the other has a middle name too. I want to get all of them separately while knowing which name belongs to which person, like:

```
foreach ($persons as person){
   if( person has midname){
       $value1 ="name"; $value2= "midname"; $value3="surname"
   }
   else
       $value1="name"; $value2="surname"   
}
```

Comment: Protip: Never assume anything about people's names

Comment: Unless the string is coming from an outside source, this is not a very good way to store people's names.

Comment: thanks Juhana, they are coming from an HTML form, and the format is:
 name surname, name surname, name midname surname ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will help you out a lot:

```
$str = "name1 surname2, name2 midname2 surname2";
$people = explode(',', $str);
foreach($people as $person)
{
    $names = explode(' ', $person);
    switch(count($names))
    {
        case 3:
            $value1 = $name[0];
            $value2 = $name[1];
            $value3 = $name[2];
            break;
        case 2:
        default:
            $value1 = $name[0];
            $value2 = $name[1];
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As rightly noted by [dm03514](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594589/dm03514): this will not work if the person has a space in any of their names (i.e. a last name of 'De Luca'). However, this is as close as you're going to get without some sort of restrictions or validation enforced at the source of the names.

Comment: what about if a person has a space in his or her last name? ie 'De Luca'

Comment: thank you Andrew. but i do not know which person might likely have midname. point is constant array indices are no good..

Comment: I think you misunderstood where those array indices point to. Andrew's code does what you asked for.

Comment: thanks Juhana. you are perfectly right, i misunderstood the code at first sight.

Comment: @dm03514: Good point, but I don't really know of any way to account for that within the given parameters.